# JSRuntime not playing sound when initializing Blazor web app

Tags: javascript, audio, blazor

So I have this simple page:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<button @onclick="MakeSound">Make sound</button>
<button @onclick="ShowPopUp">Show pop-up</button>

@code
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("makeSound");
        _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showPopUp");
    }

    void MakeSound()
    {
        _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("makeSound");
    }

    void ShowPopUp()
    {
        _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showPopUp");
    }
}
```

in which I have 2 buttons: one for playing a sound and one for showing an alert.
They work fine but when I try to run these actions at initialization, only the alert message shows up and there's no sound. Why?

By the way, this is the JS, though I have a feeling that the problem is not here:

```
function makeSound() {
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/ding.wav");
    audio.play();
}

function showPopUp() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: Ill be very surprised if you can do this especially in production...

Comment: Most browsers block auto clips that try to play on page load. That's most likely why it works with a button click but not when trying to play it during initialization.  That the alert works but the audio doesn't seems to confirm this. For details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement#examples

Answer (score 0):

Calling JavaScript function in OnInitialized do not work, because DOM is not rendered yet, OnAftrRender is the right event to call JavaScript functions. So you can try like this

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
       if(firstRender)
       { 
           _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("makeSound");
           _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("showPopUp");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, but this is unlikely to fix the problem. The script loads the audio file dynamically when called.   The page render is separate.